# Searching in a Tree that is NOT BINARY

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

Hey guys,
I have created a tree which is not a binary tree. Now, what I want is to search for an element. The main thing is the following: Since I have no comparison chance in contrast to a binary tree, I have to find some other ways to implement the code. Here what I thought:

```
public TreeNode<City> search(City parent, TreeNode<City> t){
//As you guess, City class is irrelevant to the issue, I have no problem with City class.
    if (t.getCity().equals(parent)) {
        return t;
    }
    else if (t.hasLeftChild()){
        search(parent,t.getLeftChild());
    }
    else if(t.hasNextSibling()){
        search(parent,t.getNextSibling());
    }
    else//Since I know that case will never happen, the returned value is unimportant
        return t;
    }
```

Of course, that code did not work. The difficult part is that I have to return the value I am searching for as soon as I find it. Yet, If I cannot find it, I still have to return something. How am I going to do that???

Comment: It would be more helpful if you told us what kind of tree it *is*, rather than what kind of tree it is *not*.

Comment: Actually, the tree is something I created and I don't know if there is a spesific name for it, guess shouldn't be.

Comment: How many children can each node have? is there any limit? This _sounds_ like an [N-ary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ary_tree).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, you need to (somehow) use the value returned by the recursive calls to `search()` — probably `return` it:

```
public TreeNode<City> search(City parent, TreeNode<City> t){
    if (t.getCity().equals(parent)) {
        return t;
    }
    else if (t.hasLeftChild()){
        return search(parent,t.getLeftChild());
    }
    else if(t.hasNextSibling()){
        return search(parent,t.getNextSibling());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more precise Matt? As you can guess, that method does not even compile.

Comment: Sorry, I left off the last case. It doesn't compile because you need to always return a `TreeNode<City>`.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I cannot understand. I guess that should work, thanks Matt=))

Comment: !!!
I guess that code also has a problem: 
The odd thing is that: Assume there is only one element in my tree. Then, when I try to add an element to my tree, the method works properly. However, when there are two elements(a parent and a child) and I search for the child, what is printed on the screen is "ccc" and what the code returns is null!!!

Comment: I don't see any print statements in the code, so I really can't help there.

Answer (score 0):

metacode for the recursive function you are looking for

```
public TreeNode<City> search(City parent, TreeNode<City> t){
    if (t.getCity().equals(parent)) {
        return t;
    }

    if (t.hasLeftChild()) {
        if (tmp = search(parent,t.getLeftChild())) {
            return tmp;            
        }
    }

    if (t.hasnextSibling()) {
        if (tmp = search(parent,t.getnextSibling())) {
            return tmp;            
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: `false` is a boolean, not a `TreeNode<City>`.

Comment: What should be returned is something of type TreeNode<City>, not boolean. I still need to fix the final "return false" part of the code.